# Unable to launch Firefox browser in Windows Xp (32 bit) Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation

I am unable to launch the firefox browser (49 version) and with Selenium Jar is 2.5.3 .

Getting Below error:-

```
*2016-11-10 18:45:36 ERROR BrowserConfig:293 - Error in EbselenCore.setBrowser:Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'karthik', ip: '0.0.0.0xx', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown*
```

Even i tried with the system.setproperty to the

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "xxxxx\\xxx\\firefox.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "xxxxx\\xxx\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.bin", "xxxxx\\xxx\\chrome.exe");
```

Even i tried with the chrome driver :-

```
Nov 11, 2016 2:29:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForErrorSEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:Process exited with an error: -1073741511 (Exit value: -1073741511) 2016-11-11 14:29:11 ERROR BrowserConfig:293 - Error in EbselenCore.setBrowser:Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46' System info: host: 'karthik', ip: 'x.x.x.x.', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumChromeDriver
```

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: This error will come when the firefox is not installed properly. Can u try reinstalling it once?

Comment: If you open a command prompt window and type cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\ do you see a binary file named firefox.exe? If not, that is your problem; no firefox browser.  When running local, Selenium expects both its firefoxdriver and your firefox browser to be installed.

Comment: @KarthiikRao Can you make a clean install of a stable GA release of Mozilla Firefox & share with us your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium 2.5.3 only work with firefox 46 and older. You need to use selenium 3 and newer from firefox 47 onwards. You also need to use geckodriver.